# Error with Mixed Effect Model when trying to use a continuous variable

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I am trying to use lme4 to run a mixed effects model.  When I run it with a binomial y variable it seems to work fine.

AccMetPrev.lm = lmer(Correct ~ 1 + Mratio * Prevalence_Level + (1+ Mratio |RECORDING_SESSION_LABEL) + (1|INDEX) + (1|targetcategory), data = VSMRatiodata, family = binomial)

[image]

However, when I switch to a continuous variable it is not giving me any p values and is for some reason separating my targetcategory variable.  Both of the examples are essentially running the same model except that I am removing "family=binomial"

VerMetPrev.lm = lmer(Verification ~ 1 + Mratio * Prevalence_Level + (1+ Mratio |RECORDING_SESSION_LABEL) + (1|INDEX) + (1|as.factor(targetcategory), data = VSMRatiodataTP)

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question and include the output of `str(VSMRatiodata)`  and `summary(VSMRatiodata)` and please describe how the data were generated and what your research question is.